# Angular with Google Tag Manager

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular7, google-tag-manager

Am working with Angular 7 Project, Its a SPA Web App. When am using Google Analytics Code with GA Preview. Tracking is Perfectly Working. But when am trying to add Google tag Manager. its not working correctly. I tried with **History Change** AND **All Page View** also in tag Manager. In this SPA Web App Page changing is triggering in analytics through tag Manager. But Bounced rate is not Showing correctly.

While Using Analytics My Bounce Rate will show around 55% to 70%..

When Am Start using Tag Manager My Bounce Rate will show around 5% to 10%.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending Analytics hits twice. Check trigger for you Analytics tags in GTM.

Comment: Hi Sir, Can You please provide me some Steps for adding tag manager with analytics for SPA websites. Because I want to check that, If i did anything wrong or not.

Comment: Try to follow this guidelines: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/